# Pycaret cross validation scores are way lower than unseen test set scores

Tags: cross-validation, binary-classification, pycaret

How come the cross-validation model scores are much lower than the model scores on an unseen dataset?

```
# 'data' is a dataframe with 600K observations. 
# the label is 'top_percentile' which is 0 in 95% and 1 in 5%

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_data, test_unseen_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)

# make sure that both datasets contains also 1 label
print(train_data.groupby('top_percentile').size())
print(test_unseen_data.groupby('top_percentile').size())

from pycaret.classification import *
exp1 = ClassificationExperiment()
exp2 = ClassificationExperiment()

exp1.setup(data=train_data, train_size = 0.9, target = 'top_percentile', session_id = 123)
exp2.setup(data=train_data, train_size = 0.9, target = 'top_percentile', session_id = 123, fold=20)

print('cross_validation=False:')
model1 = exp1.create_model('rf', cross_validation=False)
exp1.predict_model(model1, data=test_unseen_data)

print('cross_validation=True:')
model2 = exp2.create_model('rf', cross_validation=True)
```

Expected that cross-validation scores will be >= test score

[image]
[image]
[image]